# Magento 2 - Difference between building a theme from scratch and inheriting from Blank theme

Tags: magento2

I'm so confused between whether I Should inherit my custom theme from Blank theme or start a new one from scratch.
Please what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Building theme from scratch means no need to inherit parent theme like Blank or Luma.
If you want to use components of Luma/ Blank theme and want to write less CSS or less then you have to inherit parent theme.
Building new theme from scratch means you have to manage all file Email,Print all CSS you have to Write that.
Best theme Development resources.

https://jamersan.com/lets-get-started-theming-magento-2-part-1/

Source: Jamersan.com